# Desktop folder disappeared, Desktop has been replaced by 'Home'

Tags: directory, 17.10, desktop-environments

I rebooted into Ubuntu from W10, and i saw folders like 'Music', 'Documents' etc. on my Desktop.

- I deleted them from desktop; but they also got deleted in Home
  folder.So they don't behave like shortcuts or copies.
- I tried this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus` and nothing happened.

Ubuntu 17.10

Edit:

```
dogus@DogusUbuntu:~$ cd Desktop
```

When I write cd Desktop, it yields:

> bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory

and

```
dogus@DogusUbuntu:~$  ls
```

Yields home folders such as 'Documents', 'Downloads', etc.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/147152/home-directory-messed-up and sounds as if you need to make a directory for Desktop, not sure from what you posted as you did not include the full output of `ls` command.

Comment: Yes, as it appears my desktop path had been corrupted. I redefined it and after reboot, my problem was solved.Thank you!